# Restoring saved model with dropout applied from java program

Tags: java, tensorflow, seed, dropout

I have a pre-trained model with dropout applied and I want to restore it from java program.

With my application, in the inference step, I need to turn on dropout and repeat feeding input to the model multiple times and get an array of predictions.

What I did:

1. Load the model and initialize a session

```
model = SavedModelBundle.load ("path_to_model", "serve");
sess  = model.session();
```

2. Feed to the model (Repeat multiple times, eg. 3 times)

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    t_pred = sess.runner().feed("x", x).fetch("y").run().get(0);
```

Let's assume:

- 1st time: Get an array A1 = [y1, y2, y3]
- 2nd time: Get an array A2 =[z1, z2, z3]

...

I want the same inference but A2 is different from A1. 
I know that the dropout mask is changed over time.
I guess I need "seed" variable as what we have in python API. But I couldn't find any reference.

What I tried:
To get the same prediction list, I need to load the model and initialize the session multiple times.

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    model = SavedModelBundle.load ("path_to_model", "serve");
    sess  = model.session();
    t_pred = sess.runner().feed("x", x).fetch("y").run().get(0);
```

But it is not optimal as it takes time to load the model and can cause memory related problem.

How can I solve the issue?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I solved the problem.

I was wrong to think that the session is reinitialized when reopening the session: `Session s = modelBundle.session();`

It is reinitialized with a graph involved.

```
byte[] metaGraph = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(save_path));
Graph g = new Graph();
Session sess = new Session(g);
```

But it causes the error:

> "Attempting to use uninitialized value "

I fixed the bug by changing the way to save the model in python.

Previously, I used:

```
builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(save_folder)
builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess,[tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING])
save_path = builder.save()
```

It seems to not save a seed (initialized as local variable) then it caused the model not save the state.

I change it to:

```
with tf.gfile.GFile(save_path, 'wb') as f:
   f.write(out_graph_def.SerializeToString())
```

and it works well^^.